# Changing voice parameters in TextToSpeech (Kotlin, Android Studio)

Tags: android

I'm developing an Android application in Kotlin using TextToSpeech for speech synthesis. I need to change voice parameters such as speaking speed and tone. I've already used the setSpeechRate and setPitch methods but ran into some limitations. For example, how do I install a male voice?

Here is part of my code:

kotlin

`val textToSpeech = TextToSpeech(this, this)`

// Voice settings
`textToSpeech.setLanguage(Locale("ru"))`
`textToSpeech.setSpeechRate(1.0f)`
`textToSpeech.setPitch(1.0f)`

// Play text
`textToSpeech.speak("Hello world!", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null, null)`

How can I further change voice parameters such as gender and other characteristics?

I would be grateful for any advice and code examples!

1. I read the documentation for TextToSpeech, but did not find information about additional voice parameters.
2. I tried the setSpeechRate and setPitch methods, but I want more flexibility.

Comment: You cannot change the gender of the voices. This is technically not possible. But of course you can add male or female voices, see e.g. [here](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/voices).